# How can i show only one item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, view, actioncable

I have a chat on action cable. I change my show action for this:

```
def show
  @rooms = Room.all
  render 'index'

  if @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

But i need to show to user a single room with another information. I create action:

```
def single_show
  @room = Room.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

It gives me only first room regardless from room which i choose. I understand it's from 'find_by', but i need to show every room which user choose. When i choose a room i get this route in browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/single_show.2
```

I think it's not right. My routes is:

```
resources :rooms
get 'single_show', to: 'rooms#single_show'
```

How I can show every room which user will chose?

Answer (score 0):

Please change routes
`get 'single_show', to: 'rooms#single_show'`
to
`get 'single_show/:id', to: 'rooms#single_show'`

````
def single_show
  @room = Room.find_by(id: params[:id])
end```
````

Comment: GIve up arrow so other can prefer this solution

Comment: How can i do it?